# Any working library for uploading file on reactnative?(android)

Tags: react-native

I've been searching through the net for a working library and test them all, and it seems none of them is working so far on android. Preferably with headers support.

P.S. I've just recently used https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob, here's my code, but found too many bugs.

```
    RNFetchBlob.fetch('POST', `${my_upload_url}` {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'Transfer-Encoding': 'Chunked'
      }, [{
        // NOTE: my server requires the 'data' key 
        name: 'data',
        filename: '${file_name_of_file_path}',
        type: `${file_type_of_file_path}`
        data: RNFetchBlob.wrap('my path to file')
      }, {
        // NOW: how would I add more params with the same key?
        name: 'data',
        data: queryString.stringify({
          ...some params
        })
      }])
      // listen to upload progress event
      .uploadProgress((written, total) => {
        // NOTE: another weird thing only fires once, with 1
        console.log('uploaded', written / total);

      })
      // successfully uploaded
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('on upload success:', response);
      }).catch((err) => {
        // error here is: Error: unexpected end of stream on Connection
        console.log('on upload error:', err);
      });
```

P.P.S I've used https://github.com/tranquangvu/react-native-uploader, but there's no support for header in android.

Comment: could you please tell me what technology do u use on backend?

Comment: I'm not actually sure, but I think we are using node

Comment: I've just send you an answer. hope this help you

Answer (score 2):

[react-native-fetch-blob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob) are still maintained and supports both android and iOS

Comment: Does it support for uploading video also?

Comment: I've edited the the question, the bugs are there in comments

Comment: can you please add it in another question to get noticed by all

Answer (score 0):

I've used [react-native-interactive-avatar](https://github.com/Osedea/react-native-interactive-avatar). you could handle uploading image with onChange props of that. also [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html) could help you for saving image on your device.